# Tutorial adding sensor to robot. Error/Bug?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In this tutorial when I insert my_robot I get a grey screen from Gazebo, and in the console it says "Waiting for model database update to complete".

Then says "Unable to connect to model database...".After this starts giving errors. Is there anyway I can simply download the model of the Hokuyo sensor? Why is this even connecting to some database? There is something really wrong with this tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8029/tutorial-adding-sensor-to-robot.-error/bug?/) by [Paulo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1111/paulo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can clone the `gazebo_model` database, and copy it into `~/.gazebo/models` using:

```
cd ~
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models
cp -r gazebo_models/* ~/.gazebo/models
```

The error message "Unable to connect to model database" means that either you don't have an internet connection, or the gazebo web server is down.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paulo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1111/paulo/) on 2015-02-17**:
thx you. I copied the model I needed and it works now.